# Is there a plant particularly suitable for absorbing Hydrogen Sulfide

Tags: botany, plant-physiology, photosynthesis

I live in an area with some open sewers and in the morning I can usually can smell the gas inside my house.

There are many plants like snake plant which improve indoor air quality but I was wondering if there are any that are particularly useful for absorbing sewer gas (hydrogen sulfide)